# AES encrypt/decrypt file using Chilkat Encryption C / C++ Library

Tags: c++, encryption, exe

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt file using Chilkat Encryption C / C++ Library.

Here is example which I use:

http://www.example-code.com/cpp/crypt_aes_encrypt_file.asp

Here is what I did. I downloaded library from

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_vcpp.asp

and extracted it. I created new project, Win32 Console Application and pasted code from link above (I modified path to CkCrypt2.h and included iostream library). I linked library ChilkatDbg.lib (I'm using Visual Studio 2013), but I get a lot of errors when I try to compile application. There are 3 other libraries: ChilkatDbgDll.lib, ChilkatRel.lib and ChilkatRelDll.lib.  Here is one of errors:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3@YAXPAXI@Z)   c:\Users\hae\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ChilkatDbg.lib(ZeeDeflateState.obj)  ConsoleApplication4

I can't paste all of them since body of message is limited.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of the library did you download (32-bit or 64-bit)? And which of Visual Studio's toolchains are you using (the one targetting x86, or amd64)?

Comment: Thanks for reply Michael, I saw  that I downloaded wrong library, I have 64bit system but I used 32bit library. I downloaded now 64bit library but I got these errors:

Comment: 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CkCrypt2::CkEncryptFile(char const *,char const *)" (?CkEncryptFile@CkCrypt2@@QAE_NPBD0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ChilkatSample(void)" (?ChilkatSample@@YAXXZ)

Comment: 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CkCrypt2::SetEncodedIV(char const *,char const *)" (?SetEncodedIV@CkCrypt2@@QAEXPBD0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ChilkatSample(void)" (?ChilkatSample@@YAXXZ)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CkCrypt2::SetEncodedKey(char const *,char const *)" (?SetEncodedKey@CkCrypt2@@QAEXPBD0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ChilkatSample(void)" (?ChilkatSample@@YAXXZ)

Comment: 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CkCrypt2::UnlockComponent(char const *)" (?UnlockComponent@CkCrypt2@@QAE_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ChilkatSample(void)" (?ChilkatSample@@YAXXZ)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\hae\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I use Runtime Library - Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

Comment: Based on those error messages it looks to me like you're using a 32-bit toolchain. Visual Studio includes both 32-bit and 64-bit toolchains, and IIRC you have to actively specify that you want to use the 64-bit one. I don't remember exactly how you do that, but you can try searching on MSDN or google.

Comment: What is exactly 64-bit toolchain? I relatively recently started programming so I didn't master terminology yet :)

Comment: I mean the compiler/assembler/linker and associated tools that generate 64-bit executables. Just because you're running Visual Studio on a 64-bit _host_ doesn't mean that it will automatically generate code for 64-bit _targets_.